# apply function to rolling window in panel data in R

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, rollapply

I'm trying to apply a function (say standard deviation) in a rolling window, by category:

I have the following data:

```
cat = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B") 
year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993) 
value = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 4, 5) 
df = data.frame(cat, year, value)
```

I would like to create a new column (say sd) that estimates the standard deviation over two year window by cat.

Here's the result I'm thinking of:

[image]

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by using `rollapply` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)

cat = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B") 
year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993) 
value = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 4, 5) 
df = data.frame(cat, year, value)

df$stdev <- unlist(by(df, df$cat, function(x) {
  c(NA, rollapply(x$value, width=2, sd))
}), use.names=FALSE)

print(df)
##   cat year value     stdev
## 1   A 1990     2        NA
## 2   A 1991     3 0.7071068
## 3   A 1992     5 1.4142136
## 4   A 1993     6 0.7071068
## 5   B 1990     8        NA
## 6   B 1991     9 0.7071068
## 7   B 1992     4 3.5355339
## 8   B 1993     5 0.7071068
```

You can also do it with `ddply` if you'd rather use `plyr` functions than `by`:

```
df$stdev <- ddply(df, .(cat), summarise, 
                  stdev=c(NA, rollapply(value, width=2, sd)))$stdev
```

As a lark, I did a `system.time` (multiple times) comparison of the above two methods and also the `ave` method pointed out by [@thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803/thelatemail) in the comment thread below this answer (starting with a "fresh" copy of the data frame).

```
df <- data.frame(cat, year, value)
system.time(df$stdev <- with(df, ave(value, cat, FUN=function(x) c(NA, rollapply(x, width=2, sd)))))

df <- data.frame(cat, year, value)
system.time(df$stdev <- unlist(by(df, df$cat, function(x) c(NA, rollapply(x$value, width=2, sd))), use.names=FALSE))

df <- data.frame(cat, year, value)
system.time(df$stdev <- ddply(df, .(cat), summarise, stdev=c(NA, rollapply(value, width=2, sd)))$stdev)
```

Both the `ave` and `by` methods take:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.000   0.002
```

and the `ddply` version takes:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.004
```

Not that speed is really an issue here, but it looks like the `ave` and `by` versions are the most efficient ways to do this.

Comment: thank you, but it's not quite right - i want those standard deviations to be grouped by "cat". can i use ddply or something similar here?

Comment: No need for `unlist(by(...))` - `ave` is probably more appropriate: `with(df, ave(value, cat, FUN=function(x) c(NA, rollapply(x, width=2, sd)) ))`

Comment: Nice. Didn't think of `ave`. It does `interaction(...); split(x, g) <- lapply(split(x, g), FUN)` under the covers so it does alot under the covers.

Comment: A slight simplification could be had by using `rollapplyr` with the `fill=NA` argument: `ave(df$value, df$cat, FUN = function(v) rollapplyr(v, 2, sd, fill = NA))`

Comment: [@G](http://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck) Now I want to go back and add that to the time tests! That's prbly the best all around solution.